# Programatic generation of OData Proxy

Tags: odata

There is OData Service using WCF Data Services  (ADO.NET Data Services) available.
I need to consume the OData Service in programmatic way. In the sense I do not want to use DataSvcUtil to create the proxy. Instead at runtime I need to generate the OData Proxy.

For WSDL, it is possible to generate the proxy using CodeDOM and System.ServiceModel.Discovery.

I am curious to know whether there is any programatic way of generating the OData Proxy.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DataSvcUtil uses this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.design.entityclassgenerator_members.aspx to generate the code. So you can do the same. Once you have the source code generated, call a compiler on it (I think CodeDOM can do that as well) and load the result dll.
It takes an XmlReader so you will have to create an XmlReader from the $metadata enpoint of your service, but that's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Damn! I was so close to getting this working, but it seems that EntityClassGenerator doesn't generate entity types that implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which I need in order to be able to use the proxy in my app. Can't see any configuration options on EntityClassGenerator.

Comment: Did you try setting the EntityClassGenerator.UseDataServiceCollection=true? It enables data binding on the generated classes, part of which should be to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found it a few minutes after I posted - the name of that property misled me... My dynamic data service client is now working great with very little code. Thanks for the original tip!

Comment: Dear Wayne, do you have any sample code you wish to share to perform a dynamic data service client?